# longpoll XHR vs iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, xmlhttprequest, comet

I'm implementing typical server-push (comet) application. I'm choosing between two options: the longpoll XHR and iFrames. What are pros and cons of these? I know about the cross-site restrictions and that iFrame is pretty heavyweight component... are there any other differences? For example the "reliability" of the transport or level of control over the component?
What do you think, is there a single right answer which approach is better or there are use cases for both of them?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I got a pretty good working XHR implementation, but I want to consider the alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use socket.io or an equivalent library. It supports both ways you mention and more:

http://socket.io/#transports

However, let's assume your using an appropriate abstraction layer, and now want to decide which transport to use. :)

IMO, the deal-breaker for iframes is error handling. The continuously loading iframe technique makes it *much* harder to do error handling. You're not informed via a convenient event of 404s or timeouts, so you have to set an interval in the JavaScript to watch for errors.

Supposedly iframes have less overhead than making a new XHR/HTTP request to reconnect after every message, but when I tried it all I saw was increased memory overhead on my server and zero responsiveness improvement; probably it depends on your choice of backend.

Another interesting factoid is that browsers are limited to two concurrent requests to a server by the standard, but Mozilla made an exception for XHR only:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest

When you're making long requests, the 2 connection limit is really important: if you tie up both pipes, nothing else will be able to get through! You have to be care to set up a single channel that all the code on the page shares. But on Firefox, you now get some wiggle room, if and only if you use XHR.

Iframes do have the advantage of being able to make cross domain requests.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a third option: [*websockets*](http://websocket.org/). The websockets api is an evolution from long polling and is developed for real time client-server communication.

The protocol isn't supported by all browsers so you actually still need to support long polling when websockets aren't available.

There are libraries that degrade nicely (if websockets are available they use those, else they fall back to long polling). You have [socket.io](http://socket.io/) (supports all browsers). A jQuery alternative is [jquery-graceful-websocket](https://github.com/ffdead/jquery-graceful-websocket). Both libraries expose the websocket api but fall back to alternatives for the communication if necessairy.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to potentially worry about if it's going to be smartphone friendly is that carriers can and will mess with data as it goes through their network. Normally to compress it.

Since the iframe method kind of streams a webpage with some JS in it, it *looks* more like a webpage to the carrier and is more likely to be messed with by a carrier. In this instance, them cacheing it up so that it can't leak through would be my primary concern - they are unlikely to change the meaning of your actual JS.

An XHR (especially if you're actually returning XML) is less likely to be messed with by the carrier.

Of course, a good carrier will understand what is going on and let both methods work. Not all carriers are good, though.

A difficult thing to judge and plan for but worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean comparing iframe to longpull, but in my opinion iframes are very risky and make developing harder many times because of mentioned by you browser restrictions. And from the other side longpull XHR should be simplier to implement with your current XHR implementation. It also gives synchronizing comparing to asynchronous XHR.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly XHR is the cleaner solution and has all the previously mentioned benefits.

Since the code is easily implemented, I suggest you do both and test on a number of platforms.  Create two apps which will display the number of missed polls, and beg a dozen friends to run the app on as many of their devices as possible.

Then report back!

Answer (score -1):

I think longpoll XHR is a better route to go for a couple of reasons:

1. It's the future. iFrames are loosing ground fast.
2. I think it's a better seperation of data and display. You can get the data, and then handle the display in the client. This will also allow you to have the same data source and display it differently for different platforms. Display in a PC web browser would be different than display on the iPhone.